# Is there way to actually move allocated object to std::list

Tags: c++, c++17

In C styled linked list you just set pointer to allocated object, while in C++ copy seems unavoidable.
Naive test code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;

struct LinkedS{
    LinkedS *next = nullptr;
    float f;
    std::vector<float> v{1};
};

struct S{
    float f;
    std::vector<float> v{1};
};

int main()
{
    S* s = new S;
    cout << &s->v.front() << ' ' << &s->f << '\n';
    std::list<S> li;
    li.push_front( std::move( *s ) );
    cout << &li.front().v.front() << ' ' << &li.front().f << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/33T4179Gj
Here vector content is actually moved, but struct data is still copied unfortunately.

Comment: Why are you allocating `S` with `new` when you want to move it? That's counterproductive

Comment: What do you mean by "struct data is still copied unfortunately"? Default move constructor calls move constructor of every member.

Comment: I'm not sure what your output is trying to show. If anything it shows that `li.front()` now owns the data previously owned by `*s`, showing that the move did occur. What output did you expect which would show that "struct data is not copied"?

Comment: While floats are movable, it still is a copy.  moving only applies to types that have pointers to data inside them.  It allows you to swap the pointers between the moved to and moved from objects, leaving the move from object "empty".

Comment: @UnholySheep `new` happens inside algorithm, then some decisions are made, and only then insertion optionally occurs.

Comment: "you just set pointer to allocated object" You seem to be describing intrusive linked lists, or perhaps linked lists of pointers rather than embedded values. C++ has all these too, this is not really a C vs C++ question. In C++, `std::list` owns the elements. You need a different data structure (e.g., Boost.Intrusive has a collection) if you want intrusive linking. Does this clarify? Right now it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen POD types are copied, `std::vector` shell is copied too, only vector data is actually moved. Wished behavior would be like what happens in C linked list (copying a pointer).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i would expect both pointers staying the same, as if list just copied a pointer to object instead of making struct copy.

Comment: @Garux `move` doesn't move an object, it moves a value. An inviolable rule of C++ is that the address of an object can never change no matter what. `s->f` is going to occupy whatever address it occupies until it is destroyed. It is strictly impossible to change the address of `s->f` such that it now resides within the list. For trivial types like `float` moving its value is identical to copying it.

Comment: @GManNickG the purpose is to make insertion cheaper by copy avoidance. I assume `std::list` does the same `new` under the hood. Of course providing such cheap way might be risky, if you allocate object by different means.

Comment: @Garux Please edit your question to include the C code you have in mind, otherwise we're guessing at what requirements you feel aren't being met. It really sounds like your C linked list is of the intrusive variety, or that it manages pointers to your data rather than holding it directly.

Comment: @Garux Consider using `emplace_back` and passing constructor arguments instead of using `push_back`. It constructs the object in-place instead of using a temporary intermediary. Another solution is to use a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<S>>` instead which will make adding elements only need to set a pointer, in addition to the normal overhead of allocating and linking a node. Also consider using `std::vector` if you are concerned about speed. It has good performance in most cases, and it is probably going to be faster than `std::list` is most use cases.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i'd expect list just grabbing pointer to object instead of doing own `new S( s )` under the hood, so both pointers would point the same. But it sounds like C++ is designed in a different way.

Comment: @GManNickG alright, intrusive linked list was implied, added example struct.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `std::unique_ptr` sounds like an option, if copy avoidance is wanted stronger than `std::unique_ptr` overhead. `std::list` was chosen because in code its data is referenced by different structs.

Comment: @Garux `unique_ptr` is free of overhead compared to equivalent correct code that would use raw pointers. The cost of indirection and pointer assignment is the same as-if raw pointers were used. But worrying about performance is often misinformed. The performance impact of using `std::list` is very likely to dominate any other performance concern shown here. And even then, in the majority of applications performance doesn't matter as long as it is "fast enough" (usually as compared with requirements). Start by worrying about righting correct and clear code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i totally agree here. Actual code even works slightly faster after switch from intrusive lists. The purpose of question was to know if there is designed opportunity to make such insertion even cheaper.

Comment: If you're not using list splicing (probably the only reason to consider lists), then `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is almost certainly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage of `new` is not a good C++, it is not Java/C#, do not use `new` unless you have to and when you have to, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Are you looking for `emplace_front`, `emplace_back`? They can construct the stored object at its final destination.

### C++20

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>
struct S{
    float f;
    std::vector<float> v;

};

int main()
{
    std::list<S> li;
    li.emplace_front(42.4f,std::vector{1.f,2.f,3.f,4.f,5.f});
    
}
```

### C++17

Sadly prior to C++20, a constructor is required, aggregates do not count.

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct S{
    float f;
    std::vector<float> v;
    S(float f, std::vector<float> v):f(f),v(std::move(v)){}
};

int main()
{
    std::list<S> li;
    li.emplace_front(42.4f,std::vector{1.f,2.f,3.f,4.f,5.f});
    
}
```

If you really need to pass a pre-allocated pointer to a container, it is not possible. `std::list` is not a linked list *per se*, it only has requirements on operations that will likely lead to linked-list implementation. Furthermore all STL containers use customizable Allocators and each allocator owns and provides the storage for its container, it cannot be passed in from an external source.

Although there are some recent exceptions for associative containers with `std::map::extract` and `std::map::insert` operating on nodes. In theory, `std::list` might get them too in the future.

### True linked list

Nothing is stopping you from creating `std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and working with that.

Comment: `std::map::extract` is not much of an exception since you still can insert extracted elements only from another `std::map`. Furthermore, you can do that already between lists using `std::list::splice` and `merge` without `extract`.

Comment: @eerorika True, to be honest I though the nodes were at least constructible from `pair<K,V>`, I never had to use them. Sadly another thing that was left unspecified.

Comment: @Quimby the question is about case, when `new` is required: `new`, do things, optionally insert to container. `std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>` might work, if copying is worse, than its overhead (in real code copy happens more rarely than regular `emplace` you describe). It seems that using `std::list` with one entry and then `splice` shall be least costly.

Comment: @Garux I probably wouldn't use `list<unique_ptr<T>>` because it is very unlikely that twice as many allocations and indirections is going to outperform the move constructor. You can also write your own `List` class with the functionality of taking ownership of a raw pointer.